# Have I proven this limit correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Prove that the sequence $a_n$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then:

$\left | \frac{1}{n}-0 \right |=\left | \frac{1}{n} \right |=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$

Thus, $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

We may choose $n(\epsilon)=\left \lceil \frac{1}{n} \right \rceil\in\mathbb{N}$. In conclusion $\forall n>n(\epsilon)$ we have:

$\left | a_n-a \right |=\left | \frac{1}{n}-0 \right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\right |=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.

If this is incorrect, can somebody please walk me through the steps I have to go through in order to prove a limit. I've always been bad with proofs so usually I just sort of memorize them instead of actually understanding how they work.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The two lines after "Then:" where you figure out how to choose $n$ do not have to be included, but it doesn't make it wrong. It's like showing scratch work on an exam.

Comment: I'm aware of that but i still included it since in my country professors don't really do any scratch work, they just include everything in the proof.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the definition of convergence, you want to prove that exist for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $n$ that for every $m>n$ you have that $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$ with $L$ your limit. With that in mind the  essence of what you did it’s ok, the only thing it’s that you have a certain $\varepsilon$ and then you pick an $n$, if you are making this by definition it’s important to say that not every $n$ accomplish $$1/n<\varepsilon,$$ but you pick one that works and then follow the idea that for every $m>n$ $$|a_m-0|<|a_n-0|=1/n<\varepsilon$$ and then it’s totally proved.